# Looking for help creating a custom URL button for Docusign

Tags: button, salesforce, docusignapi

I'm essentially looking for the syntax that would provide a different DST based upon the billing state of the record I am launching the docusign from in Salesforce.

Answer (score 2):

Salesforce Lightning no longer allows JavaScript buttons for various security reasons, because of this we no longer can use our standard JavaScript custom buttons. Starting in DFS 7.0 we now have a custom button builder which will be a great way to go, however, there are currently limitations to that builder that code can solve.

try this:

```
{!URLFOR('/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope', null, [
SourceID = Opportunity.Id,
CCRM = 'Decision Maker~Signer 1',
CCTM = 'Decision Maker~Signer',
DST = 'a2e2cd02-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-c9f2b6564a9e',
LA = '0',
LF = '0',
OCO = 'Tag'
]
)}
```